# .NET assembly with Revoked certificate over OCSP - what happens?

Tags: c#, .net, authenticode, ocsp

I'm a little new to dealing with signed .NET (C#) assemblies (we have an EXE and several DLLs), so there might be a few simple things that I am missing.  I recently found an application we were using was taking a very long time to load on a machine with no internet access (well, HTTP was blocked) and tracked it down to a OCSP request timing out after several tries.

In reading about [OCSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol), I discovered that one of the possible response you can get is "Revoked".  What happens when you try to run a .NET executable and the OCSP check comes back as revoked?  Do you see an error?  Can you still run the program after clicking through a warning?

What I'm worried about is this essential legacy application suddenly failing to run if the original signer decides to "revoke" the certificate (and I don't even know what the process for that is).